# How do I store an image to disk in Java?

Tags: java, image

I'm using httpclient to download images from a webpage and I'm trying to save them to disk but not having much luck. I'm using the code below to fetch the image but not sure what needs to be done next to actually get it to disk, the fetch would be on a JPG or a PNG image path... thanks

```
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE,HttpClientFetch.emptyCookieStore);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(pPage.imageSrc);
        HttpResponse response;
        response = httpClient.execute(httpget, localContext);

        Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for(Header h: headers) {
          logger.info("HEADERS: "+h.getName()+ " value: "+h.getValue());
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


        Header contentType = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Type");

        byte[] tmpFileData;

        if (entity != null) { 
          InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
          int l;
          tmpFileData = new byte[2048];
          while ((l = instream.read(tmpFileData)) != -1) {
          }
        }
```

tmpFileData should now hold the bytes of the jpg from the website.

Comment: wouldn't using a fileOutputStream.write(byte[]) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (entity != null) { 
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream("YourFile");
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(instream, outstream);
}
```

Comment: Using this example, Java shows an error because YourFile doesn't exist. Why is this happening, I assume that this script is trying to create this file, not reading from it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FileOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and its `write` method.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outputfilename");
out.write(tmpFileData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use Apache commons-io, then you can just copy one InputStream to one OutputStream (FileOutputStream in your case).